# What does it mean for this proposition to hold in $Top_*$?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, stable-homotopy-theory

In chapter 2 (or 1 depending on your edition) of their text *Foundations of Stable Homotopy Theory*, Barnes and Roitzheim have a certain Proposition 2.1.9 (or 1.1.9) saying that if $A\to X$ is an h-cofibration which is a $k$-equivalence between $(k-1)$-connected spaces, the quotient $(X,A)\to(X/A,*)$ induces isomorphisms on low-dimension homotopy groups ($n<2k$) and an epimorphism on a certain homotopy group ($n=2k$). This part of the result is standard enough. However, they then add that the result holds in $Top_*$, the category of pointed spaces, provided both $A$ and $X$ are well-pointed. It's unclear to me exactly what this means, since as far as I can tell the statement is the same for pointed spaces (the h-cofibrations are the same, k-equivalences and k-connectedness are the same, and quotients are the same).

The only interpretation I could think of is that if $A$ and $X$ are well-pointed, then the span diagram defining the pushout (for the quotient) is half-cofibrant over a left proper model category, so $X/A$ is homotopy equivalent to the space obtained by adjoining the reduced mapping cone. However, while this allows a construction similar to the unpointed case, I don't see why this is necessary, as the result appears to carry over directly.

Comment: Let $f:X\rightarrow Y$ be a map in $Top_*$. The inclusion $X\hookrightarrow M_f$ into the (reduced) mapping cylinder of $f$ may fail to be (free) cofibration if $Y$ is not well-pointed. If both $X,Y$ are well-pointed, then $X\hookrightarrow Mf$ is both a pointed and unpointed cofibration. Hence the assumptions are used on literally the first line of the proof (i.e. $C_f\simeq X/A$)

Comment: I see how this can be used to produce a pointed version of the proof, but I don't see why this is necessary; it seems to me that the pointed and unpointed statements are completely identical. To be specific, even in the pointed case, I don't see why we can't simply forget the point, since the theorem has no pointed information.

Comment: The mapping cylinders and cones in $Top_*$ are the reduced versions. The canonical map from the unreduced to the reduced versions of these spaces need not be homotopy equivalences without some cofibrancy assumptions. For instance, if $j:A\hookrightarrow X$ is a free cofibration, then $\widetilde C_f\rightarrow C_f$ may fail to be a homotopy equivalence. But $\widetilde C_f\simeq X/A$, so the proof runs into problems on the first line. The assumptions the authors make are sufficent but not strictly necessary.

Comment: I see. So what you're saying is that the additional assumption is needed to transport the proof, but the result is still valid regardless?

Comment: Not quite. The assumptions the authors make transport the proof and guarantee the statement. What I'm saying is that the statement will hold for many non-well-pointed spaces too. For instance I think it would be sufficient to assume h-well-pointedness. But such extra generality is rarely useful in practice.

Comment: I suppose I'm just failing to see why the statement could fail for statements which are not well-pointed. If we have some h-cofibration $A\to X$ in $Top_*$, can we not forget to $Top$ and apply the non-pointed form of the theorem there?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108468/discussion-between-doron-grossman-naples-and-tyrone).